# Change message "You are not authorized to access that location." in plugin cakedc/users with cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0, cakedc

Im tryng to change the message

> You are not authorized to access that location.

with cakedc/users plugin with cakephp 3.1 but I cant find the way.

This is my configuration in  src/Controller/AppController:

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('CakeDC/Users.UsersAuth', [
         'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
      ]
     );
    }
```

But still the message:

> You are not authorized to access that location.

What im doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> What im doing wrong?

You're not configuring the plugin as intended. As stated in the docs:

> [...]
>
> The plugin is configured via the Configure class. Check the `vendor/cakedc/users/config/users.php` for a complete list of all the configuration keys.

**https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/3.1.1/Docs/Documentation/Configuration.md**

To configure the Authentication component options, use the `Auth` key, either in the config file as described in the linked docs

```
$config = [
    // ...

    'Auth' => [
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        // ...
    ],

    // ...
];
```

or via `Configure::write()`

```
Configure::write('Auth.authError', 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my configuration in src/Controller/AppController:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authError'    => 'Você não está autorizado a acessar este conteúdo!',
        'authorize'    => ['Controller'],
        //
    ]);
    // 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try change the file
 **vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php** on line 454, the `authError` key.

```
'authError' => __d('cake', 'You are not authorized to access that location.')
```

Comment: screwing with sources when configuration is available is always a bad idea